# Display Name of Current View Controller in Alert

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to display an alert if the view controller being shown on screen is "PrimaryViewController" I am not sure exactly how to get the name of the view controller and then convert it to an NSString... Any help would be extremely appreciated!!!

```
//get name of current view controller
UIViewController *currentVC = self.navigationController.visibleViewController;
if ([currentVC isEqualToString:@"PrimaryViewController"])
{
    //display name of current view controller in alert    
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
initWithTitle:@"Your current view controller:" message:currentVC delegate:nil 
cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`NSStringFromClass()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIIABFJ). It returns the name of a class as a string.

**Sample Code :**

```
if ([NSStringFromClass([currentVC class]) isEqualToString:@"PrimaryViewController"])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Your current view controller:" message:NSStringFromClass([currentVC class]) delegate:nil 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
initWithTitle:@"Your current view controller:" message:NSStringFromClass([currentVC class]) delegate:nil 
cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I am also getting an error at the "if ([currentVC isEqualToString:@"PrimaryViewController"])" line that says "No visible interface for uiviewcontroller declares the selector isequaltostring" any ideas why?

Comment: yes, do not check the view controller with isEqualToString, check it with `[currentVC isKindOfClass:[PrimaryViewController class]];`, anyway you don't really need to check for that equation if your only purpose right now is to display the alert with class name, just remove the `if` completely

Comment: duh, check for the vc class [currentVC class] iskind etc. my mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can use as

```
if ([NSStringFromClass([self class]) isEqualToString:@"PrimaryViewController"])
```

Use this to get name of your class:

```
NSString * name = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
```

OR

```
NSString * name = NSStringFromClass([currentVC class]);
```

Comment: Thanks Maulik, I am getting a warning that says incompatible pointer types initializing nsstring_strong with an expression of type class... any ideas why? thanks!1

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
 UIViewController *currentVC = self.navigationController.visibleViewController;

 if ([NSStringFromClass([currentVC class] isEqualToString:@"PrimaryViewController"])
    {
     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"    
     message:NSStringFromClass([currentVC class]) delegate:nil 
     cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok",nil)       
     otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

     [alert show];

    }
```

Good luck!